# Is there an easy way to tell if a site is running expression engine?

Tags: content-management-system, expressionengine

I have tried looking for

- Common paths for template files
- Admin pages
- Meta tags

Seems to be really easy for drupal/wordpress/textpattern - are there any quick tricks for ee?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the easiest (and best) way to determine if a website is running ExpressionEngine is to inspect the cookies set by the site.

By default, an out-of-the-box ExpressionEngine installation names its cookies with the prefix `exp_`:

[image]

Naturally, these [Cookie Settings](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/admin/system_admin/security_settings.html) *(Cookie Domain, Cookie Path and Cookie Prefix*) can be overridden in the Control Panel, but many people never bother to change it from the default.

If they have, the prefix will be different but the rest of the cookie name will be unchanged.

For example, compare the following two cookies:

```
exp_last_visit        // Default EE Website
cms__last_visit       // Website for CampaignMonitor
```

You'll notice both cookies have in common `last_visit` (and so on for all cookie names).

You can test out this newfound knowledge on these popular, high-traffic ExpressionEngine:

- [A List Apart](http://www.ilounge.com/)
- [CampaignMonitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/)
- [iLounge](http://www.ilounge.com/)
- [Obama-Biden Change.gov](http://change.gov/content/home)

While there isn't a reliable way to determine what CMS a site may be running, trying to guess the [system folder](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/installation/best_practices.html) path, asset names, common paths and templates is time-consuming and not always indicative of the truth.

Comment: Wow hadn't even thought of that approach! It's a bit harder to get to but much more reliable it seems. Will see if I can use this approach for the other CMSs too.

Answer (score 9):

I use the "BuiltWith Technology Profiler" that I have installed on Google Chrome. Not fool proof but I use it all the time to see what has been used to build sites (not just ExpressionEngine).

Get it [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/builtwith-technology-prof/dapjbgnjinbpoindlpdmhochffioedbn)

Answer (score 3):

You can also look at the source of the site's Search tool (provided they're using EE's Search module) ... it will contain some EE-specific hidden fields:

[image: EE Search hidden fields]

Comment: Thanks! I think that's a really simple way of finding out and I guess *most* sites will have search - I'll certainly look into it!

Answer (score 0):

All URLs are default after index.php, i.e.
http://www.testing.com/index.php/testing
Many times they are rewritten, i.e.
http://www.testing.com/testing
So, a good way to tell would be to try to access any URL by adding a base directory of index.php.  At least that's the only public way on our sites.  We rename our admin folder as do many others so as to not allow that to be easily figured out by the public.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not sure whether this would be unique to ee though, I've seen a couple of other sites that do this